# git reset --hard isn't resetting the files

Tags: git, git-tfs

I'm using git-tfs and I'm having issues with files changing arbitrarily.

When I run

```
git reset --hard
```

it says I'm at the appropriate commit, but that I still have pending changes. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

[image]

And here's my config

[image]

Comment: Did you check out a project with case-sensitive filenames onto a case-insensitive filesystem?

Comment: that's a very good question @CarlNorum, and one that I don't have an answer to. my NTFS file system is case sensitive. Any advice on how to fix?

Comment: What does it show the differences are?

Comment: @carlnorum it's the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this has to do with `core.autocrlf` changing your line endings. Have you tried with `core.autocrlf=false`?

You may have to delete and checkout the files again, or even try `git tfs clone` again from scratch with `core.autocrlf=false` (globally).

Comment: I think you're right. I re-checked out the files and it doesn't seem to be happening any longer. I set autocrlf to false simply because it was recommended by [@coridrew](https://twitter.com/coridrew) in one of her meetups on git-tfs

Comment: autocrlf=true has its uses, but I've found that autocrlf=false more often keeps me out of trouble when working with git-tfs.

Comment: git-tfs set locally `autocrlf=false` when cloning to avoid problems (and I think it's the better thing to do, even globally, on windows)